# Need Help on ROPC flow with Azure AD B2c Custom Policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

we are trying to implement ROPC flow in Azure AD B2C.

I have gone through the B2C Advanced policies and the instructions provided as per below links to configure with B2C Custom Policies and facing some issues.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/scenarios/source/aadb2c-ief-ropc

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/B2CROPC/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com_B2C_1A_ResourceOwnerv2%20SINGLE%20FILE%20-%20Copy.xml

Though we have provided correct username and password, we are getting

> {
>       "error": "access_denied",
>       "error_description": "AADB2C90225: The username or password provided in the request are invalid.\r\nCorrelation ID:
>   8c15d7ab-ba5b-4baf-be5a-8bfdb9939164\r\nTimestamp: 2019-01-23
>   06:18:19Z\r\n" }

Comment: Hi @Bharani: The definitive guide for configuring ROPC is [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/ropc-custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/ropc-custom). Are you using an authentication request like this: `https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token?p=B2C_1_ROPC_Auth`?

Comment: I am using the same url as mentioned. But still no luck.

Comment: were you able to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve this problem. In my case, I followed this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/ropc-custom

But had the same error message.
In step 4 I had to add values for "client_id" and "resource_id". I used the values that I had in another profile ("login-NonInteractive").
And the flow worked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered your ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework application as Native?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom
Registering the ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework application as WebApp/WebAPI might result in this error.

Comment: I have reistered ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework as native and IdentityExperienceFramework as WebApi and provided access to ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework app from api access. And provided application ids of PIEF and IEF as client_id and resource_id within custom policy respectively